# Is property or field 'ServerRelativeUrl' part of the command Get-PnPFolderItem

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I am getting the following error while using the command "Get-PnPFolderItem"

```
Get-PnPFolderItem : The property or field 'ServerRelativeUrl' has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

I checked the documentation and there is no reference of it

```
Get-PnPFolderItem
[-FolderSiteRelativeUrl <String>]
                [-ItemType <String>]
                [-ItemName <String>]
                [-Web <WebPipeBind>]
                [-Connection <SPOnlineConnection>]
```

Comment: i don't understand what i have seen online ... but they consistently mention that you need to load the root url using something like `Context.Load()`. again, i have no understanding of HOW to do that since all the references i find are c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my test, the command `"Get-PnPFolderItem"` works fine on my environment. So, yes it should be part of the command Get-PnPFolderItem.

Please maek sure the version of your SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline is the lastest. Also try to connect another site and check if it works.

Comment: updated the PnPSharepointOnline module and the mentioned error is not showing up. @Michael Han_MSFT - what do you mean by - "So, yes it should be part of the command Get-PnPFolderItem". What should be part of Get-PnPFolderItem ?

Comment: The -FolderSiteRelativeUrl Parameter.